# How can I combine two rows of a dataframe based on some condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My input looks like this:

```
output
Ohio State
nan
nan
New York City
nan
nan
nan
```

And I want to be able to convert the input to the following format

```
output
Ohio
State
nan
nan
New
York
City
nan
nan
nan
```

I was thinking to make a flag column where I/p is not null, but can't really think how I can include that logic in code

Comment: it looks like a list and not a dataframe, can you share a sample of the df? do you need to split string with more that 1 word with whitespaces between them?

Answer (score 0):

If you have `dataframe` like this :

```
#Test dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'output' : ['Ohio State', np.nan, np.nan, 'New York City'
                               ,np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})
```

**code**

```
lst = df['output'].str.split().to_list()
pd.DataFrame((more_itertools.collapse(lst)))
```

**result**

```
       0
0   Ohio
1  State
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    New
5   York
6   City
7    NaN
8    NaN
9    NaN
```